# List items side by side with alternating list-style images

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to manipulate a list to list items side by side, which I have accomplished by using a float, but that causes an issue as there will be no way to automatically clear the float for the user. This list will be automatically created, the user doesn't have any control over the code, so the list will simply be `<ul><li>Item</li></ul>` there isn't a way to clear a float for the user, so maybe using the float isn't the best option? I'm open to other suggestions.

Also, I would like to use one list-style image for all items on the left side and one image for all items on the right side. I did try using `:nth-of-type(1)` and `:nth-of-type(2)` but that only added the image to the first and second, I don't know of a way to say "every other" in CSS.

I made a fiddle to make it easier to see:

https://jsfiddle.net/nywmxkur/1/

*Edit:* Also, using this method seems to align the text of the list-style image to the bottom corner, I could like to align the text to the top corner if that's possible?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using `:nth-of-type()`, you can simply do it with `li:nth-of-type(odd)` and `li:nth-of-type(even)` - http://jsfiddle.net/0xyuwh5s/.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that! You've taught me something new, thank you!

Comment: Take a look of this excellent article - https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/ meanwhile, you might be also interested in this - http://jsfiddle.net/59zgLey6/ so the text flows to the bottom of the icons if that was what you asked for.

Comment: I actually ended up not using a float at all, which seems to have solved an issue when the first item was long and the second was really short, I used display: inline-block & display: -moz-inline-box to work with firefox. In regards to the list-style-image I changed that as well and used a background image and used padding to move the text over, which actually gave me exactly what I wanted. But that article is excellent! I'm learning so much today! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the nth-child selector.

```
.pagecontent li:nth-child(2n + 1) {
    list-style: square inside url("http://www.illstudios.com/bullet1.png");
}
.pagecontent li:nth-child(2n + 0) {
    list-style: square inside url("http://www.illstudios.com/bullet2.png");
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly! I guess I didn't read enough on the nth-child. Quick question, do you know how I can align the text within the <li> to the top of the image and not the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

What about `nth-child(2n)` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child))?
You can target even items with `2n` and odd items with `2n + 1`.

See this update to your fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/nywmxkur/2/

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you! Unfortunately though, Tyler Ortiz beat ya by a few minutes, but I really appreciate your answer!

Comment: It's not a matter of who answered first, it's about the quality of the answer. I read your comment to the other answer. The best way to get a reply to that is to add it to your original question -- or you can open a new question altogether.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I didn't mean to offend if I have, the answer both of you posted were correct and solved my problem! I solved my other issue myself, so all is well! Thank you!

Comment: It not about offending (I didn't take offence. Why should I?). I was just explaining how StackOverflow works. Answered questions remain available and searchable, so that future visitors can find and benefit from them. The emphasis should be on the _quality_ of the answers, not the timestamp.